# Node js calling function at different time intervals

Tags: javascript

I am new to node js and I need to know how to go about this problem.

I have a function block that has to be spawned at different intervals.

The same function has to be called parallely.ie
Say the time intervals are 1,2,3 sec

One starting and being called at 1sec time gap
One starting and being called at 2sec time gap
One starting and being called at 3sec time gap

All three should start at the same time

Comment: This is not node-specific but standard javascript: you should lookup *setTimeout*.

Answer (score 0):

Just set them up with a loop and timeouts, e.g

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(i) {
    console.log(i);
  }, i * 1000, i);
}
```

See also `setInterval`